# How to access solr using solrj

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm new to solr and i'm trying to index some files using solrj. I already did http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-3_6_1/doc-files/tutorial.html .

But now I would like to use solr with solrj. I would like to send pdf files and get them indexed.

I have already found a tutorial but i get CommonsHttpSolrServer is deprecated errors.

Are there any good tutorials around to use solrj? What jars do I need to import etc..?

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj is of course a good starting point. The first google result while searching for "SolrJ" by the way :)

Comment: Yeah but I couldn't find          From /lib 
•slf4j-jdk14-1.5.5.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the solrj source & test codes inside the solr folder when you download [apache-solr-src](http://ftp.itu.edu.tr/Mirror/Apache/lucene/solr/3.6.1/) file.

In the following path you can find test codes for Solrj which will help you understand how to use Solrj.

> apache-solr/solr/solrj/src/test